# Using Arrow Buttons To Scroll Window Horizontally

Tags: jquery, navigation, horizontal-scrolling

Basically I have a website with horizontally scrolling content. As in the whole page scrolls horizontally, not just a div.

I am trying to implement left and right arrow buttons that onmousedown or hover (it doesn't matter too much which one yet), scrolls the whole window (smoothly) left and right.

This website does pretty much what I want with the little centred arrows: http://www.clholloway.co.za

Can anyone help with this? Cheers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think with a little bit of jQuery you can achieve what you are looking for. The basic idea is to handle some event (onmouseenter, mousedown, etc...) that you can then use to kick off the scrolling.

Imagining you have some markup that looks like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="contentBlock">1</div>
    <div class="contentBlock">2</div>
    <div class="contentBlock">3</div>
    <div class="contentBlock">4</div>
    <div class="contentBlock">5</div>
</div>
<span id="panLeft" class="panner" data-scroll-modifier='-1'>Left</span>

<span id="panRight" class="panner" data-scroll-modifier='1'>Right</span>
```

And a few styles to ensure it will cause the window to scroll:

```
#parent {
    width:6000px;
}
.contentBlock {
    font-size:10em;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:400px;
    height:400px;
    width:500px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
.panner {
    border:1px solid black;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:45%;
}
.active{
    color:red;
}
#panLeft {
    left:0px;
}
#panRight {
    right:0px;
}
```

You can use a combination of styling, setInterval, and jQuery.scrollLeft() to achieve the effect you want.

```
(function () {

    var scrollHandle = 0,
        scrollStep = 5,
        parent = $(window);

    //Start the scrolling process
    $(".panner").on("mouseenter", function () {
        var data = $(this).data('scrollModifier'),
            direction = parseInt(data, 10);        

        $(this).addClass('active');

        startScrolling(direction, scrollStep);
    });

    //Kill the scrolling
    $(".panner").on("mouseleave", function () {
        stopScrolling();
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    //Actual handling of the scrolling
    function startScrolling(modifier, step) {
        if (scrollHandle === 0) {
            scrollHandle = setInterval(function () {
                var newOffset = parent.scrollLeft() + (scrollStep * modifier);

                parent.scrollLeft(newOffset);
            }, 10);
        }
    }

    function stopScrolling() {
        clearInterval(scrollHandle);
        scrollHandle = 0;
    }

}());
```

Full jsFiddle demonstrating this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/atAHh/

Comment: Thanks this is absolutely perfect! You've solved a big headache! And with a very small change, you can convert it to scroll onmousedown (if anyone is interested, I've altered the fiddle here to work onmousedown not hover: http://jsfiddle.net/atAHh/2/).

Answer (score 2):

I have created this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emgee/Cdzuy/) for you to help. Take a look and see if it helps point you in the right direction. You'll likely have to adapt it to your situation, but hope it does what you need.

Please note I put `overflow:hidden` on the `<body>` so explicit scrollbars don't display; change if desired.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If the you set the `body` element to a width larger than the view port (and don't set overflow hidden) the browser will support horizontal arrow key scrolling automatically.  It's the same as using the vertical arrow scrolling on this web page.

Comment: I'm aware - but the automatic left/right arrow key scrolling is too slow and not smooth enough, in my opinion. So ideally I think the easiest way to get round this is putting in buttons that scroll the browser window left or right. I'd also be happy if I could get the arrow keys to smooth scroll as you press them and then stop as you release - but I'm struggling, because JS isn't my strongest language!

Comment: Nothing can be faster or smoother than native scrolling. If you catch the events in JS you're continuously executing the JS runtime, which then tells the browser view to scroll, adding a layer and slowing it down. The only other thing you could do is catch the keydown in JS and then scroll much further than it normally would, but that would be jarring for the user.